# Open disc in $\mathbb{C}$ with arbitrarily large radius

Tags: complex-numbers, infinity

I was wondering whether it is accurate/allowed to assume that an open disc in $\mathbb{C}$ centred at the origin with an arbitrarily large radius can be considered equal to $\mathbb{C}$ itself.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Can be considered" for what purpose?  It's obviously not the same thing.

Comment: In the sense that if there exists some sequence of open discs centred at 0 where as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the radius of the open discs also approach infinity. Then does its limit equal to $\mathbb C$ itself?

Comment: For what purpose?  I can certainly see reasons why one might want to think of a plane as a kind of generalized disk.  I can also probably come up with conditions under which it would be best not to.  What is the end goal, here?

Comment: @Aester What you are asking is that is essentially the same as : Is there a natural number $n$ such that $\{0,1,...,n\}$ can be considered "equal" to $\Bbb{N}$ itself. Obviously not. There's a difference between finite sets and infinite sets. But in the case of the complex plane, the issue is much deeper. It is a problem of total boundedness/precompactness, i.e., any sequence of points in a disc of any fixed radius (no matter how large) will have a cauchy subsequence. This cannot be said in the case of $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: An open disc in $\mathbb C$ with arbitrarily large (finite) radius is the result of choosing a single element from a set of open discs in $\mathbb C$ whose radii are unbounded from above, and no such element is equal to $\mathbb C,$ regardless of the set of open discs you choose from and regardless of the open disc that is chosen.

Comment: What is "an arbitrarily large radius"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you stick to the strict logical truth on this issue.

It is certainly true that
$$\bigcup_{r>0} B_r = \mathbb C
$$
where $B_r = \{z \in \mathbb C \,\mid\, |z|<r\}$.

It does not follow that there exists $r>0$ such that $B_r=\mathbb C$. And on top of that, it's just plain false: for any $r>0$, the number $z=(r+1) + 0i$ is in $\mathbb C$ but not in $B_r$.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear, but in a comment you amplify it to mean, is there a sense in which $\lim_{r\to\infty}D_r(0)=\mathbb{C}$?

It is obviously true that $\bigcup_r D_r(0)=\mathbb{C}$. So you could *define* the limit of a family of subsets to be its union. However, people generally don’t do that because it’s clearer just to explicitly state what you mean. In some contexts the “limit” you want might be the intersection, and in still other contexts something else.

If this question arose while trying to prove some theorem, better to ask about that.